# Word Replacement (using The R Language)

Tags: r, replace, character, cpu-word

I am trying to replace a word using R language

I used If function to replace words in R. It is working fine. But, if the workd starts with lower case or Word is in UPPER case, it is not replacing. For eg: If I want to replace Apple, I used if code to replace it with Apples. If the column contains APPLE or AppLE, it is not replacing. Can someone help which function to use to replace a work irrespective of lower and uppercase

I use If function in R script

Comment: You could use `gsub` with `ignore.case = TRUE`.  Try this, for example... `gsub("ap", "pur", "APPLE", ignore.case = TRUE)`.  See `?gsub` for more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to solve the problem is to change your column to either all lower or all upper.

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
        col_0 = c(1,2,3),
        col_1 = c("aPPLE","apple","grape"))
df %>% 
mutate(col_1 = tolower(col_1)) %>% 
mutate(col_1 = str_replace(col_1, "apple", "orange"))
```